# Setting up logging for buckets in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Hey I don't what to write in the end of my command please help me.

[image]

Comment: Kindly provide a detailed description of what you tried and the problem faced. Go through the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation [gsutil logging set on](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/logging)

> The "gsutil logging set on" command will enable access logging of the
>   buckets named by the specified URLs, outputting log files in the
>   specified logging_bucket. logging_bucket must already exist, and all
>   URLs must name buckets (e.g., gs://bucket). The required bucket
>   parameter specifies the bucket to which the logs are written, and the
>   optional log_object_prefix parameter specifies the prefix for log
>   object names. The default prefix is the bucket name. For example, the
>   command:

```
      gsutil logging set on -b gs://my_logging_bucket -o AccessLog gs://my_bucket1 gs://my_bucket2
```

You should use a **gs://URL** (an existing bucket) , you are using **only gs://** on your command

```
      gsutil logging set on -b logging_bucket [-o log_object_prefix] gs://kookipedia-logs
```

This command will output log files for **gs://kookipedia-logs** in the specified **logging_bucket**.

Answer (score 1):

1) There should be two different buckets in the command -- the bucket at the end of the command is the bucket you're generating access logs for, and the bucket after the `-b` flag should be the bucket those logs get stored in.

2) The `[-o log_object_prefix]` part of example command that you copied is in square brackets, which indicates that it's an *optional* parameter you can provide.  If you want to turn on logging for all objects in your bucket, rather than only logging objects with a specific prefix, you can just leave the `-o` argument out:

```
gsutil logging set on -b gs://BUCKET_YOUR_LOGS_SHOULD_GO_TO gs://BUCKET_TO_TURN_ON_LOGGING_FOR
```

If you wanted to include the `-o` argument, you'd provide it **without** square brackets:

```
gsutil logging set on -b gs://BUCKET_YOUR_LOGS_SHOULD_GO_TO -o /some/object-prefix/ gs://BUCKET_TO_TURN_ON_LOGGING_FOR
```